# Laravel 6 - 404 not found when trying to access to the register form

Tags: laravel

I have changed the route for register (from `"/register"` to `"/dashboard/users/register"` ), i want to create new users via the admin panel(only admin can create new users). But when i try to access to `"/dashboard/users/register"` it returns `404` not found.

route

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and check for issues.

Comment: Is the form still available on its original url? Then you might need to ```php artisan route:clear```

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict with the route name. Try to change the name from 'register' to other value like 'dashboard.user.register'. Apart from that, you can check you don't have `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);` in your routes where you are removing the register route

Comment: 1- @ceejayoz i don't have issues i get the full list of my routes

2- @MartijnICU i tried `php artisan route:clear` still not working 
3- @Alejandro i changed the name to 'dashboard.user.register` still the name. I deleted `Auth::route()` to change my routes

Answer (score 1):

It could be this line

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```